# ThreadSanitizer (tsan) - Suppression files vs blacklist files

Tags: clang, clang++, thread-sanitizer

Is there a difference between ThreadSanitizer [suppression files](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/wiki/Suppressions) and [blacklist files](https://code.google.com/p/thread-sanitizer/wiki/Flags#Compiler_Flags_(LLVM-specific))? -- when used by the llvm-specific compiler flag of -fsanitize-blacklist=

When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

ASFAIK blacklisted code doesn't get tsan instrumentation at all, while suppressed code is a runtime thing so the supressed code still get monitored by tsan but simply not reported, so that a report won't get polluted by known races.

This can make a performance difference.